# C# Session Variables/Application-wide Variables

Tags: c#, session-variables

I'm new to `C#` from `ColdFusion` and I'm trying to replicate an application I have developed in CF to help me get an understanding of the language.

My application logs a user in and searches and buys virtual items.

In my CF app, when a user logs in I set a session variable called `loggedIn` which is `true`.

Each `search/buy` request can only be made whilst this session variable is `true`. If a request returns a expired session response from the host then I update `session.loggedIn = false`. A new login request is then made.

How would I achieve this in C# so that I don't need to pass it to and return it from each class/method that it interacts with?

Basically, in CF I can set and access it from anywhere within the application but is this achievable in C#?

Comment: Is this question specific to ASP.NET WebForms, or ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: I would suggest that you do not attempt to copy your code from `ColdFusion` to `C#`. The patterns are going to be different and this might not be the best approach in a different language. I suggest you take a look at the Identity 2 framework, this will handle what you want, it's a framework for authentication and user identity.

Answer (score 0):

Your logged session could be a class that you instantiate when the user logs in, an that you invalidate/destroy when it expires.

Then you shoul move the relevant methods *inside* that class, so they can always be executed because they only exist within the scope of the active session.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to set a session value, then you can use the `Session` property, which is available to a WebForm, or Controller (it's not clear if you're using WebForms or MVC).

Either way, using that proeprty is the same for both e.g.

**Writing**

`Session["loggedIn"] = true;`

**Reading**

`bool isLoggedIn = Convert.ToBoolean(Session["loggedIn"]);`

I suggest you create a property on your WebForm/Controlle to wrap this functionality e.g.

```
public bool UserIsLoggedIn
{
    get
    {
        if (Session["loggedIn"] != null)
        {
            return Convert.ToBoolean(Session["loggedIn"]);
        }

        return false;
    }
    set
    {
        Session["loggedIn"] = value;
    }
}
```